# Access to path denied but the file has no restrictions

Tags: c#, windows-10

I'm new to C# and not an expert at programming in general, but I can't seem to figure out what is causing this problem.  I am letting the user pick a XML file and then I want to read it's contents.  This is in C# making a universal windows 10 app

This is the error I'm getting:

> An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\temp\file.xml' is
>   denied.

```
public async static void pickFile()
        {
            FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
            openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xml");

            StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

            if (file != null)
            {
                var t = Task.Run(() => { reset(file.Path); });
            }
       }
```

then

```
private static void reset(string path)
        {
            String LocationDatafilename = path;
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(LocationDatafilename, settings);
            XmlDocument LocationDataXml = new XmlDocument();
            LocationDataXml.Load(Globals.reader);
        }
```

When I get to `XmlReader.Create` that's when I'm getting the error.  When I look for the cause, the only thing I find is due to permissions, but that isn't the case.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: How did you determine permissions isn't the case? Who has what [NTFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/277867) permissions?

Comment: Try to put the file in your desktop folder and see if you can load it from there. It is probably a problem with file permissions so UAC is blocking the access.

Comment: If it isn't a permissions issue, it could be that the file has a read-exclusive lock from something else, or that the file has the read-only attribute set.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "traditional" permissions but it's due to the Store App being sandboxed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to operate on the `StorageFile` directly, since your app doesn't have permissions to directly read the user's files. You can either use the WinRT XML API or you can keep using the .NET API and use the stream-based `Create` function instead of the one that takes a file name.

Comment: awesome, this got me headed on the road I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run sysinternal's ProcMon app, and at the same time run your application. Find the file in the procmon capture, and in the CreateFile entry, you'll find the creation Disposition. This will give you a clue why the creation failed. Also, select the "User" column to show the user performing the operation.

Comment: You can't work around these types of issues for Windows Store apps if you ever intend to submit them.

Answer (score 0):

While Peter Torr's answer is correct and is the way Microsoft wants these things to be done, it is possible to make (at least parts of) the OP's code work as well. The `reset` method will work, if the path is to one of the directories you have permission for. To get these you can use `ApplicationData.Current`. This object contains properties like `LocalFolder`, `LocalCacheFolder` or (what could be interesting for your use case) `SharedFolder`.